# CassiniDev embedded in WinForm app?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, cassini-dev

I am trying to put together a winform app that also has a web interface that can interact with events generated from within the winform portion of the app. I am successfully running the cassinidev server from within the app and asp.net pages are being processed but I am still running into a few obstacles and I am not sure if they are even possible???

1. I am unable to use code behind pages. I have added the appropriate
   attributes to the page directive but I still cannot access controls
   from the aspx page.
2. I am unable to access classes from the web portion of the app. See
   screenshot...

Maybe what I am trying to accomplish is not even possible but if anyone can help to point me in the right direction I would be most grateful!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that since the only thing you have available is the "website path" option.
You do however have the source and if you find some way of sharing data (maybe using the ApplicationPool) you could probably do that...but i'm guessing you'd still need to cast that data on startup to a static variable in your website.
Seems like too much work 2 me.
I'd suggest selfhosting WebApi as well and then just using that as the data layer of your website.
Both can be hosted in winforms and webapi CAN share static data directly from your code :)